# Python - Check if value is unique in dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a way to check if a value is unique for a specific list, within a dictionary of lists? If yes, I would like to know in which key/list pair/s the value is present.

For example:
{1: [3, 4, 5], 2: [4], 3: [5], 6: [3, 5, 9], 8: [3 ,8]}

I want to check if 3 is present in any of the other lists within the dictionary, besides 1: [3, 4, 5(compare it with all others). Since it is, then I must receive as a result 6 and 8, because these are the keys, which corresponding lists have this value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def find_n(nums, target, exception):
    res = []
    for n, nums_list in nums.items():
        exception_key = [i for i in exception][0]
        if n != exception_key and nums_list != exception[exception_key]:
            if target in nums_list:
                res.append(n)
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = {1: [3, 4, 5], 2: [4], 3: [5], 6: [3, 5, 9], 8: [3, 8]}
    target = 3
    exception = {1: [3, 4, 5]}
    print(find_n(nums, target, exception))
```

Reuslt:

```
[6, 8]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help. I've wrote something similar, but it is very messy. Was looking for a more elegant solution. I was also curious if Python has a built in method for this.

Comment: Glad I could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can enter the value you are looking for and then loop over all the dictionaries to see if its in them.

Take this as pseudo code:

```
int val = 3

for(keys in mydict):
    if(mydict.key.contains(val())
         print(mydict.key)
```

You could also save the dictionaries in a list, so that you have a list of dicts with your corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you meant but:

```
def unique(list1):

    # initialize a null list:
    unique_list = []

    # traverse for all elements:
    for x in list1:
        # check if exists in unique_list or not
        if x not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(x)
    # printing the list:
    for x in unique_list:
        print(x, end=' ')


list1 = [10, 20, 10, 30, 40, 40]
print("the unique values from 1st list is")
unique(list1)


list2 = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5]
print("\nthe unique values from 2nd list is")
unique(list2)
```

This code will loops through all the values and ensure that they are not repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some simple helper functions like so:

```
my_dict = {1: [3, 4, 5], 2: [4], 3: [5], 6: [3, 5, 9], 8: [3 ,8]}

def keys_containing_element(dict_of_lists: dict, element: int) -> list:
    """Return all keys in dict_of_list whose list contains element"""

    return [key for key in dict_of_lists.keys() if element in dict_of_lists[key]]

def is_element_unique(dict_of_lists: dict, element: int) -> list:
    """Return true if element is in exactly one of the lists in dict_of_lists"""

    return True if len(keys_containing_element(dict_of_lists, element)) == 1 else False
```

Now,

```
print(keys_containing_element(my_dict, 3))
print(is_element_unique(my_dict, 3))
print(keys_containing_element(my_dict, 9))
print(is_element_unique(my_dict, 9))
```

outputs

```
[1, 6, 8]
False
[6]
True
```

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you for the help! This simplifies my code a lot. I've made it work, but it is a very messy solution. Was looking for something more simpler.